# How to get/collect pages names using fetch in NextJS13?

Tags: next.js, path, next.js13

I am currently building a tools website using NextJS 13 and the site will contain tools of different categories. I am having a search bar at the homepage to let the user search inside hundreds of useful tools.

App Directory Structure:

```
-app
--text-tools
---line-counter
    page.tsx
--image-tools
---png-resizer
    page.tsx
--online-tools
---youtube-downloader
    page.tsx
```

etc etc etc

And I have the following function in `@/utils/index.ts`

```
export async function fetchTools() {
    //
}
```

My question is, how can I use this function to get all the names of my tools (preferably using fetch) so the user can search them.

Thanks a lot guys!